# Work on a remote Java source code with local Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I would like to run and test my new java application on my remote server but I want to work on it from my local Netbeans. How can I do ?

Thank you very much.

Best Regards.

Comment: what kind of app?  A Webapp?  What is installed on your remote server?  Tomcat?

Comment: is remote debugging an option?

Answer (score 0):

Here is profesional solution from my company:

We use Jenkins for building java code in during a peroids called "jobs". Jenkins tests the application automatically (ex. JUnit tests). You can use GIT repository which is compatible with Jenkins, although I recommend Gerrit. And for NetBeans you can configure it to work with GIT repository, or install a plugin (Im not very familiar with Netbeans).